# How to get the postion of selected List item relative to number of list items on Screen(ListView.getChildCount)

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I need the position of selected list item relative to number of items displayed on screen. In onItemClick call back method, "position" argument gives me position of item in the total count in adapter but i need the position relative to the LV.getChildCount() i.e number of items displayed on screen. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. I cracked it, here it is: we can use LV.getFirstVisiblePosition in conjunction with LV.getChildCount and postion argument from onItemClick call back to get the position of clicked item relative to the screen count. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

```
     @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {

                     Log.i("You clicked On ", arg2+"" );

});
```

if you are using getView method in BaseAdater you will find the position related to the row you selected byt makng listeners to your listview and this position you can make it the index of your arraylist.